# is there a way to skip half of key in the properties file?

Tags: java, properties

Here is the sample of properties file

VN1234:1234 = A

Right now, we need to verify two keys (VN1234:1234) are exactly same to get value A;

But new requirement is we only need to check 1234 to get value A.

Any help will be much appreciated.

I tried to delete the first part of the key, but it is not allowed....

Comment: How do you load the properties file? Using `java.util.Properties`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use `java.util.Properties` to load that file, you can use the [stringPropertyNames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#stringPropertyNames()) method to iterate over all keys to find the one you want:

```
Properties p = ...
for(String a:p.stringPropertyNames()) {
    if(a.contains("1234")) {
        //do a thing
    }
}
```